# How to add Dropout in CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a Fashion MNIST data using CNN. Dut to overfitting I tried to add Dropout layer. But it's not working

Before I added Dropout the model was working fine.

```
def fashion_model()
    batch_size = 64
    epochs = 20
    num_classes = 10
    fashion_drop_model = Sequential()
    fashion_drop_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='linear',padding='same',input_shape=(28,28,1)))
    fashion_drop_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    fashion_drop_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
    fashion_drop_model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    fashion_drop_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
    fashion_drop_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    fashion_drop_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
    fashion_drop_model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    fashion_drop_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
    fashion_drop_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))                  
    fashion_drop_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
    fashion_drop_model.add(Dropout(0.4))

    fashion_drop_model.add(Flatten())
    fashion_drop_model.add(Dense(128, activation='linear'))
    fashion_drop_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))           
    fashion_drop_model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    fashion_drop_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

    return fashion_drop_model.summary()

fashion_model()
```

The error that I'm getting is: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`

PS: After a brief walkthrough of the code line-by-line, I figured the error was creeping in line8 (`fashion_drop_model.add(Dropout(0.25))`)

Comment: Can you show us your whole code? I don't think the problem is with the `Dropout` layers. Where are you using the variable `a`?

Comment: Which version of tensorflow/python are you using ?

Comment: Looks more like a Python error. Check your code for a spurious `a` maybe.

Comment: @VishnuDasu The variable <code>a</code> is somewhere out of my code context - probably from the module Dropout.

Comment: @ThibaultBacqueyrisses Versions: Python 3.7.3, Keras==2.2.4, tensorflow==1.13.1

Comment: You can use **tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout2D()** which drops the entire filter map for you based on the dropout probability you give as the parameter. [Click](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/SpatialDropout2D) here to know more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a colon in your Python function definition:

```
def fashion_model(): #<--
```

After you to this, the code should run.  Running this in Google Colaboratory, you'll see that a summary of your model is produced:

[image]

## Note

It is highly discouraged to use Dropout layers after Convolutional layers.  The whole point of Convolutional layers is to exploit pixels within a spatial neighbourhood to extract the right features to feed into Dense layers.  Dropout would destroy this relationship and thus prevent your model from successfully learning these features.

See this discussion on Reddit for more details: https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/42nnpe/why_do_i_never_see_dropout_applied_in/

Comment: Thanks for the help. The code is working on Google Collab but not on localhost jupyter notebook. I was using python 3.7.3 while the google collab uses 3.7.6. I changed  the version for jupyter notebook (local) to 3.7.6 and its working now.

Comment: Let me add that, although initially it was indeed thought that dropout layers should not be used after convolutional ones, there has been some more recent research indicating that there might be some benefit of doing so; see the SE thread [Where should I place dropout layers in a neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240305/where-should-i-place-dropout-layers-in-a-neural-network) and the links provided therein.

Comment: @desertnaut noted. Thanks! Looks like we can add them... Just not after pooling layers which make sense... Albeit at a lower drop rate, also making sense.